# How to reference Roslyn assemblies from an EdgeJS app?

Tags: c#, roslyn, coreclr, edgejs

I'd like to use a Roslyn library from an EdgeJS application but am not sure how to reference it properly. This is the code in question:

```
var edge = require('edge');
var toroslyn = edge.func(function(){/*
   using System;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
   public class Startup
   {
      public async Task<object> Invoke(object code)
      {
         return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("1 + 2");
      }
   }
*/
});
toroslyn(null, function (error, result) { console.log(result); });
```

And the project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
     "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting": "1.1.1",
  },
  "frameworks": {
     "dnxcore50": {}
  }
}
```

It would be nice if after doing `dnu restore` it just worked, as is, but the [documentation](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-specify-additional-clr-assembly-references-in-c-code) states I need to reference the dependencies inline like `#r "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.dll"`.

However, for it to work I need to specify the whole path to the assembly like `#r "C:/Users/Christian/.dnx/packages/....../Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.dll"` alternatively make sure all dependent assemblies are located in the same folder as my node app.

Are these the two options I have or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify fully qualified reference assembly names as an array passed in to the `edge.func` call as described at https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-specify-additional-clr-assembly-references-in-c-code:

```
var add7 = edge.func({
    source: function() {/*

        using System.Data;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        public class Startup
        {
            public async Task Invoke(object input)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    */},
    references: [ 'System.Data.dll' ]
);
```

You may find it easier to constuct fully qualified assembly names in JavaScript rather than embed as part of the `#r` directive in code.